# Documentation for Socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to make a real time canvas kinda thing with simply Node and Socket.io, but I'm having considerable trouble.

I don't know what anything means!

Socket.emit?  Socket.on?  Socket.whatever?!

Essentially, I'm coding it completely blind without any idea what in the heck I'm doing.
Do you guys know where some good documentation of socket.io is?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm using jQuery, Socket.io and Node, btw

Comment: exact duplicate of [Socket.IO documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363466/socket-io-documentation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the wiki: https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/wiki. It links to a decent number of support material for Socket.IO.

Here is a decent tutorial: http://howtonode.org/websockets-socketio

Comment: A tutorial is definitely not documentation

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at the documentation for node itself to understand the details of the methods you listed in your question (i.e. .on and .emit).  It is my understanding that socket.io is based on node.  So, [take a look at the Events documentation page at nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html).  In my opinion, though the documentation at nodejs.org and at socket.io could use a good deal of help from a professional technical writer.  The problem is that the creators of it don't have time to write documentation--they are creating useful code for the community.  Excellent documentation is one way that a language, framework, library, etc. can proliferate very quickly through a community.  It's what helps develop a literacy within the community.

Comment: One year later, the Node.JS documentation is still terrible, and vastly lacking examples.

Comment: Hello my friend @DanDascalescu . I come from the future. In 2018 it will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to read its codes under the test folder.
socket.io is using mocha as test framework, so if you are familiar to mocha, it would be easy to read how it work.

You can change the reporter as spec, and see how they test their code, then look into their source code by the test codes.